# Can I create the object of the class which is running on JBOSS server?

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jboss

Currently Learning Web project in Java. I have a doubt related to it.
Actually I have a task that, access method of Dynamic projects using JBOSS Server through web services.

Initially I didn't get what I want to do.

After learning some things related to it, I thought that If I run my project on JBOSS, then how can I access the methods of it? How to create the web service and how to use to it?

Or is it like that If I run my project on JBOSS server then is methods directly accessible?

Thats why I thought If I am able to create the object of class which is running on JBOSS server then may I can access the methods.

Please advice me on this.

Comment: please clarify... you want to access a webservice, which is running on JBoss from a remote client, is that right? What kind of webservice is it? If you're in an EJB world you e.g. can expose every remote stateless Sessionbean as a webservice, just by adding an @Webservice annotation on class level...

Comment: @Korgen : Actually I don't know what kind of web service it is. I got one link related to it as: 
http://localhost:8080/project-name/application.wadl. 

The thing is only that access methods using web service (http://localhost:8080/project-name/application.wadl)

Comment: "The thing is only that access methods using web service " I really don't understand what you are trying to say

Comment: @Korgen : Sorry for what I have written. I got link with project (localhost:8080/project-name/application.wadl) saying that "This link is for the REST web service descriptor". Using this I have to access the methods of that project. As I am new to Web Project in Java, I really don't understand what to do with that link and how to create use that "REST web service descriptor" for calling the methods. Pls help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mentioned **application.wadl** file. WADL or [Web Application Description Language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Application_Description_Language) is used to **define a contract interface** for [RESTful web services](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/ws-restful/). Please refer to the links for more information.

Now your problem boils down to :

*How to invoke the method of an object exposed as RESTful web service.*

Now you already have wadl file with you. Please have a look at a tool called [wadl2java](http://wadl.java.net/wadl2java.html).  This tool will **consume your Application.wadl** file and **generate java stubs**. You can use these generated java classes to invoke the methods on the object deployed in JBoss server.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting this tool. It works for me. Now I have the Java Stub with me, but when I try to calling the method like http://localhost:8080/proj-name/<@PATH-name in java stub>/method name, then I am able to access method. The way I am calling is it correct?

Answer (score 1):

The way you are calling it

> localhost:8080/proj-name/<@PATH-name in java stub or module name>/method name

is correct, if services is working fine for you initially, you can modify the path by editing in web.xml or path annotations in your java classes.